# Socket Server to handle multiple clients request concurrently

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, asyncsocket

I want to handle multiple client's request concurrently using Socket Server.
i have 10 clients, which can send request to my server at same time.
How could i handle this?
Is it possible?

With below code, i can handle only one request at a time, after completion of the request, server accepts next request.
Due to this 10th client need to wait until 9 requests get complete.

Any help would be appreciated

Below is the code i am using for Server Socket

```
Socket _serverSocket;
byte[] _buffer = new byte[255];

void SetupServer()
{
    try 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Setting up server...");

        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Parse(_ip), _port);

        // create server socket to listen new client's connection
        _serverSocket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        _serverSocket.Bind (ipEndPoint);
        _serverSocket.Listen (100);

        _serverSocket.BeginAccept (new AsyncCallback (AcceptCallback), null);
    } 
    catch (System.Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Server failed :: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}

void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket clientSocket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);

    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);

    clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), clientSocket);
}

void RecieveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket clientSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    int received = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

    // check if client is disconnected?
    if (received == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("client is disconnected...");

        return;
    }

    // do whatever you want with received data here...
    byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];

    Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);

    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);

    Console.WriteLine("Received Data: {0}", text);

    // accept new request
    clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallback), clientSocket);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the code you included calls `BeginAccept()` right away after handling the completion of the previous `BeginAccept()`, and so should be able to handle multiple connections without any problems. If you disagree with that assessment, please post a good, complete, concise code example demonstrating what you mean. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your quick reply.
 I, AcceptCallback, how could i differentiate multiple clients
 Socket.GetHashCode() is what i was looking for..but msdn said that its not guaranteed to give you unique id
 i am able to receive the concurrent requests, but unable to maintained the identity of client if they send another request

Comment: The "identity" of a client is its IP+port. If nothing else, you can use that to distinguish different clients. The accepted `Socket` instance itself is also an identity; i.e., when you call `BeginReceive()` on a `Socket` instance, that receive operation will only be completed for that `Socket` instance, along with whatever user-provided state object value you provide in the call. Typically, then, servers have a "user state" object that contains information specific to each client. In the simple echo-server example, you just reply on the same `Socket` for which the operation just completed.

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with the concept of a "multi threaded server". You should start a thread for each client which connects to the server. So you can simultaneously handle multiple clients. Or you could use `Tasks Parallel Library` if you want to try newer .NET features.

But there are many examples out there in the web that describe how to implement such a server.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for quick reply. As per my knowledge, using multi-threading is not efficient way, instead async socket is more efficient way. Honestly I am a newbie to socket programming, so not sure about this.